# java to android error in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have a function in java and I want to use it in eclipse in a android project:

```
public String submitForm() {
    DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
    HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
    localContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.COOKIE_STORE, cookieStore);
    httpclient.getParams().setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS, true);


    try {
        for (BasketItem item: getModel().getItems()) {
            IOUtil.getConentAsString("BZIRAN_PATH" + "/add2card.php?vendors=" + "item.getDetail().getVendors()" + "&id=" + "item.getDetail().getId()", httpclient, localContext);
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

but eclise get me an error in line 3,4:

```
    httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());
    CookieStore cookieStore = new BasicCookieStore();
```

can anyone help me to fix them:

line3 error: LaxRedirectStrategy cannot be resolved to a type

line4 error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from BasicCookieStore to CookieStore

here is import:

```
    import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.CookieStore;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;
import java.lang.Object;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.params.ClientPNames;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.ClientContext;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
```

Comment: Please show the imports.

Comment: `"item.getDetail().getVendors()"` looks weird

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import for `LaxRedirectStrategy` class

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.LaxRedirectStrategy
```

import the class `BasicCookieStore` and `org.apache.http.client.CookieStore`

```
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCookieStore
import org.apache.http.client.CookieStore
```

remove

```
import java.net.CookieStore;
```

Comment: thanks it works but it has two other error:1-in "httpclient.setRedirectStrategy(new LaxRedirectStrategy());" error "The method setRedirectStrategy(LaxRedirectStrategy) is undefined for the type DefaultHttpClient"  2-and in line 10 in "IOUtil" error is "IOUtil cannot be resolved"

Comment: for error 1: when i use httpclient4.1.jar setRedirectStrategy error removed and laxRedirect error occured, when i use httpclient4.2.3 laxredirect error removed and setRedirectStrategy error occured. what i do?

Comment: `LaxRedirectStrategy` is introduced in httpclient version 4.2 so it is not fount in 4.1. Can you give me the complete error message for `setRedirectStrategy error occured`?

Comment: i use setRedirectStrategy and LaxRedirectStrategy together. it make promlem, i try to solve it. please read my question or response to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25779685/hoe-to-change-redirect-expressin-from-httpclient-4-1-later